# How to show two intervals are homeomorphic.

Tags: general-topology

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Open_Real_Intervals_are_Homeomorphic

It says that $$f(x)=c+\frac{(d-c)(x-a)}{b-a}$$ I think I am being stupid because I just can't see it wouldn't it just be the equation of the line passing through the points $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ so $f(x)=b+m(x-a)$ where $m$ is the gradient of the two points?

Are these equivalent?

Comment: Can you find a worse title to your question?

Comment: @AsafKaragila The title has been changed.

Comment: @Michael: That's an improvement. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, your points are just confused.

If you want to map $[a,b]$ to $[c,d]$, then the left endpoint of $[a,b]$ should go to the left endpoint of $[c,d]$ so $a$ goes to $c$.  Similarly, $b$ goes to $d$.  Therefore, you need the line through the points $(a,c)$ and $(b,d)$.

The slope of this line is $\frac{d-c}{b-a}$, which is the $m$ in your comments.  Now, using point-slope form, you get the desired fraction.

Your confusion appears to be in the points $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$.  Why would you want to map one endpoint of $[a,b]$ to the other endpoint of the same interval? This doesn't make sense, you want to map it to the other interval.